# in package, how we can create a nested function using PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried to create one package . and in the package body  I defined one function.inside that funtion i tried to create another function . I used this logic because i need call that function in my procedure.can you plz help me.

```
create or replace package L2C_pkg_limit as

  function GET_CUST_PROBLEM_DETAILS return number;

end L2C_pkg_limit;

create or replace package body L2C_pkg_limit as

create or replace function nested GET_CUST_PROBLEM_DETAILS return number
is
   p_cust_diagnostic_cursor_lmt constant number(2)  :=1;

     function p_cust_diagnostic_cursor_lmt return number
     is
     begin
       return   p_cust_diagnostic_cursor_lmt;     
     end; 

   begin
     return   p_cust_diagnostic_cursor_lmt;    
   end nested  GET_CUST_PROBLEM_DETAILS;  
end;
```

Comment: Please, use proper English with proper punctuation, so that your question can be read easily. Also, please, edit your question and use the code formatting feature in the editor to format your inlined code properly to ease its reading. And welcome to stackoverflow, of course. :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `create or replace` within a package body - just declare the function using the `FUNCTION` keyword.
2. There is no keyword "nested" in Oracle. A nested function is simply one that is declared within another function or procedure's declaration section.

   ```
   create or replace package body L2C_pkg_limit as

     function GET_CUST_PROBLEM_DETAILS return number
     is
     ...
   ```